# Why remote notification doesn't work with VOIP notification for Twilio Notify service in iOS application?

Tags: ios, twilio, voip, remote-notifications

I've successfully implemented Twilio Notify API in the iOS application.

I need to get a remote notification for call status callback and VOIP notification for the incoming call indication in a single application.

But somehow all the notifications are retrieved in

`- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type`

method rather than

`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`

method.

As a result iOS application is crashing for iOS 13 and above devices as it's mandatory to report call for notifications retrieved via `PKPushRegistry`.

Can anybody help me how can I retrieve notification in
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` method?

Comment: How are you sending the pushes?  If the push includes the `voip` payload then it will be delivered as a voip push.

Comment: No, voip payload is not there. Is there any possibility of certificates which is responsible for this issue.

Comment: Have you specified `self.voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]` ?

Comment: Yes, I have specified it.